# Creating Favicon file using Intervention.io

Tags: php, laravel, imagemagick, intervention

I am trying to create a multi-resolution favicon file (*.ico) using Intervention.io (PHP library [Intervention.io](http://image.intervention.io/))? Does anyone know how to join multiple images into a .ico file?
I know how its done with imagemagik

`convert output-16x16.ico output-32x32.ico favicon.ico`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Imagick` directly, and don't bother with Intervention.io library (at least until the API can support this action).

```php
$wand = new Imagick();
$wand->addImage(new Imagick('output-16x16.ico'));
$wand->addImage(new Imagick('output-32x32.ico'));
$wand->writeImages('favicon.ico', true);
```

Comment: thanx emcconville.